# unable to presigned the uploaded file with serverless node js api issue

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, serverless, pre-signed-url

unable to presigned-url the uploaded file with serverless node js API issue, it generally happens in the us-east-2 region any idea?

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

const ID = 'some-id';

const SECRET = 'some-key';

let credentials ={
    accessKeyId: ID,
    secretAccessKey: SECRET,
}

AWS.config.update({
    credentials : credentials,
    endpoint: 's3-us-east-2.amazonaws.com',
    signatureVersion: 'v4',
    region: 'us-east-2'
  });

module.exports.upload_file = async (event, context, callback) => {
  const region= 'us-east-2', bucket= 'tt' ;

  if (!region || !bucket) {
    throw new Error('REGION and BUCKET environment variables are required!');
  }

  let file_name = event.queryStringParameters.file_name

    let ext = file_name.split('.').pop().toLowerCase();

    let content_type = '';

    switch(ext) {
      case 'png':
        content_type = 'image/png';
        break;
      case 'jpg':
        content_type = 'image/jpeg';
        break;      
      case 'json':
        content_type = 'application/json';
        break;
      case 'ai':
        content_type = 'application/postscript';
        break;
       case 'pdf':
        content_type = 'application/pdf';
        break;
      default:
        content_type = 'text/plain';
        break;
    }
    console.debug("file_name: " + file_name + " content_type: " + content_type)

  const S3 = new AWS.S3({ signatureVersion: 'v4', region : region});
  


  if (!file_name) {
    return {
      statusCode: 400,
      body: JSON.stringify({
        message: 'Missing file_name in  request.',
      }),
    };
  }

  const params = {
    Bucket: bucket,
    Key: file_name,
    ContentType: content_type,
    Expires: 30,
  };

  try {
    const url = await S3.getSignedUrl('putObject', params);

    callback(null,  {
      statusCode: 200,
      headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', // Required for CORS support to work
        'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true, // Required for cookies, authorization headers with HTTPS
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(url),
    });
  } catch (error) {
    callback(null, { 
      statusCode: 400,
      body: JSON.stringify(error),
    });
  }
};
```

unable to presigned-url s3 bucket the uploaded file with serverless node js api issue

Error says:

> The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.

Comment: The issue was it only generate the presigned url but the object is not placed yet so after this have to put the actual object like :

curl -X PUT -T ./test.png -L "signedUrl"

signedUrl is return from the serverless api 

Cors permission in the bucket (bucket can be private) for GET,PUT,POST

Answer (score 0):

According to this post on [GitHub](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/86#issuecomment-133234836), the ContentType header is used by AWS to calculate the signature of your Login (Access Key + Secret Key).

Try removing this header and test again.